# Learnable Cropping Layer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Inside a keras model, a `Cropping2D` layer can be used to crop images, which is this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(
    cropping=((2, 2), (4, 4)), data_format=None, **kwargs
)
```

Here, the dimensions has to be mentioned and so my question is:
How do make this a learnable layer, which automatically finds out the dimension and then crops it?

The aim of my model is to classify images of birds to 20 classes.
The problem is that some images have birds that are very far away, and some are enough close. So I want to crop the images to the part of the image where the bird is present and then classify it.
I cannot use techniques like YOLO because I don't have the bounding box labels. That's why I choose this way of classification:

1. Input image of 1024x1024x3
2. Use CNN to extract features and then some fully connected layers to find the bounding box and then resize the image to 128x128x3
3. Use `Cropping2D` layer to crop the image using the calculated bounding box.
4. Use a CNN to extract features from the cropped image and then an some fully connected layers to classify the image
5. Use `categorical_crossentropy` to calculate the overall loss of the model and update accordingly.

Comment: @AloneTogether I have added it.

Comment: Use Cropping2D layer to crop the image using the calculated bounding box <-- where do you get the bounding box from? What exactly do you want to learn for the Cropping layer?

Comment: @AloneTogether The cropping layer takes 4 parameters, and I want the CNN to find that and then pass it to the cropping layer. then, the cropped image is passed to a CNN to classify the image, and then categorical_crossentropy would be the overall loss of the model. This loss will be used to update the cropping CNN (which was used to find out the 4 parameters for cropping) and also the CNN used for the final classification

Comment: Yes I understand but your model has to somehow know that it is coming closer to the "desired" bounding box :D

Comment: @AloneTogether when it comes to the desired bounding box, the classifier CNN will be able to classify correctly, and so the loss will decrease, this is how the model will know